# How to split and add a new line delimiter in an xml file (using linux bash)

Tags: xml, linux, bash

I have the following xml file. I actually made a mistake while I was constructing it. I didn't add a new line after the end of the queries. What command can I use in linux in order to modify it?

```
</query><query id="...">
        ^ split here. add new line delimiter

</query>
<query id="...">
```

---

### input

```
    <queries>
    <query id="LFENT_1_1">
    <name>barack obama</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>person</type>
    </query><query id="LFENT_1_2">
    <name>obama</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>person</type>
    </query><query id="LFENT_1_3">
    <name>american</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>misc</type>
   </query>
   </queries>
```

---

## output

```
  <queries>
    <query id="LFENT_1_1">
    <name>barack obama</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>person</type>
    </query>
    <query id="LFENT_1_2">
    <name>obama</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>person</type>
    </query>
    <query id="LFENT_1_3">
    <name>american</name>
    <docid>LFDOC1</docid>
    <type>misc</type>
   </query>
   </queries>
```

---

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just adding the newline it would be like

```
sed -i -e 's#</query><query#</query>\n<query#' file.xml
```

But if you want a really nice formatted file I would suggest using

```
xmllint --format file.xml > newfile.xml
```

Comment: @HaniGoc perhaps you like the `sed` line in answer.  and it works for your input. But it should **not** be used for processing XML file. what if the XML file had a `CDATA` which contains `</query><query...`?  Or a comment section containing the same pattern? sed should not be chosen for this task.

Answer (score 4):

give this line a try:

```
xmllint --format your.xml
```

Comment: tell me what do u think @Kent  `sed -e 's/></>\n</g' input_file > output_file` . I replace the **><** by *>* to close the </query> and by *\n>* for a new line

Comment: @HaniGoc if your input is well-formed xml, and if there is "xml" way to handle it, don't use sed/awk/grep/.....  If a linebreak is important to you, I think the indents may be in same case. sed's replacement will break the indentation. You have to adjust it by yourself.

Comment: ok I get it. Better use special tools when the xml is well formed. OK

Answer (score 1):

If you want a newline after the `</query>` closing tags, you can use the following `sed` command:

```
sed  "s/<\/query>/<\/query>\n/g" input.xml
```